# Integrate Raw SQL Query into Django ORM with Aggregations

Tags: django

I'm trying to integrate this RAW query into a django ORM query but I'm facing problems to apply the raw query and the orm query

The original query which works fine with postgres querytools:

```
"SELECT SUM(counter),type, manufacturer 
FROM sells GROUP BY manufacturer, type"
```

Now I tried to integrate this into a django-orm query like this:

```
res_postgres = Sells.objects.all().values('manufacturer','type','counter').aggregate(cnter=Sum('counter'))
```

But what I get is just a the counter cnter ...

What I need is the result from the Raw query which looks like this

[image]

What I also tried is to use values and field names. Like Sells.objects.values('manufacturer'....).aggregate(cnter=Sum(counter)) 
But then django is building a query which integrates a GROUP BY id. Which is not what I need. I need an aggregation of the entire data not the object level while keeping the information of the other fields.

When I use Cars.objects.raw() it asks me about primary keys, which I also don't need.

Any hints here? is that possible with Django ORM at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`annotate(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) instead of **`aggregate()`**

```
res_postgres = Sells.objects.values('manufacturer','type').annotate(cnter=Sum('counter'))
```

Comment: THx for the answer. This gives me the object level data but not the aggregation... In my case I'm also saving a date in the database which then returns a lot of rows with separate counters...

Comment: What is the result of `print(res_postgres.query)` ?

Comment: Ah yes you are right! Sorry. Accepted your answer. Thank you very much